# Assign 1 in a matrix from a list of coordinates

Tags: r, vectorization

I want to take a list of coordinates. For every location in the coordinates, I want to assign 1 to the matrix.  The final matrix should look like this.  I want to use a fast vectorized method instead of a for loop.

```
    > sample.matrix
      A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T
    A 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    B 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    D 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    E 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    F 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    G 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    H 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    I 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    J 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    K 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    L 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    M 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
    N 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
    O 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
    P 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
    Q 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    R 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
    S 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    T 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Sample data:

```
    set.seed(15)
    dat <- data.frame(x=sample(LETTERS[1:20], 15,set.seed(15)),y=sample(LETTERS[1:20], 15,set.seed(15)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    sample.matrix <- matrix(data=0, nrow = 20, ncol = 20, dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:20],LETTERS[1:20]))
```

What I tried that worked.

```
    for ( n in 1:15){
      sample.matrix[dat[n,]$x,dat[n,]$y] =1
    }
```

What I tried that isn't working.

```
by(dat, 1:15, function(a.row){sample.matrix[a.row$x, a.row$y]=1})
```

Comment: Populating `nrow(dat)` entries out of the `length(sample.matrix)` entries of a zero filled matrix seems, also, suitable for a sparse storage -- `xtabs(~ factor(x, LETTERS[1:20]) + factor(y, LETTERS[1:20]), dat, sparse = TRUE)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This a cool programming aspect of the language. In R we can subset using a two column matrix:

```
sample.matrix[as.matrix(dat)] <- 1
```

---

**More on How it Works**

From the help for `?Extract` (bolded text is my emphasis):

> A third form of indexing is via **a numeric matrix with the one column
>   for each dimension**: each row of the index matrix then selects a
>   single element of the array, and the result is a vector. Negative
>   indices are not allowed in the index matrix. NA and zero values are
>   allowed: rows of an index matrix containing a zero are ignored,
>   whereas rows containing an NA produce an NA in the result.
>
> Indexing via a character matrix with one column per dimensions **is
>   also supported if the array has dimension names**. As with numeric
>   matrix indexing, each row of the index matrix selects a single element
>   of the array. Indices are matched against the appropriate dimension
>   names. NA is allowed and will produce an NA in the result. Unmatched
>   indices as well as the empty string ("") are not allowed and will
>   result in an error.

In your case you have a matrix with letters that represent dimension names.

```
     x   y  
[1,] "B" "C"
[2,] "S" "S"
[3,] "L" "B"
[4,] "N" "L"
[5,] "E" "G"
[6,] "M" "A"
```

When we insert this matrix into a set of brackets `[as.matrix(dat)]`, the evaluator will detect a matrix and use a special type of subsetting. The first column will represent the rows, and the second column will represent the columns.

```
head(sample.matrix)
  A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T
A 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
D 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
E 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
F 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Added the indexing tag. This is a nice example.

Comment: Thanks we should also consider creating a documentation page with both numeric and name indexing examples. Wish I had more time I think this is a unique aspect of the language.

Comment: Agree. I have found the two-way matrix indexing by (row,col) name to be useful and expressive feature.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dcast` from `data.table`:

```
dat$z <- 1
dcast(dat,x~y,fill=0, value="z")

   x B C D G H I J K L M N O P Q T
1  A 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2  B 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
3  C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
4  D 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5  F 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
6  H 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
7  J 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
8  K 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
9  L 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
10 M 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
11 N 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
12 O 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
13 Q 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
14 R 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
15 T 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: This does however drop a whole bunch of rows and columns out.

Answer (score 1):

This too works:

```
sample.matrix[t(apply(dat, 1, function(x) 
             c(which(dimnames(sample.matrix)[[1]]==x[1]),
               which(dimnames(sample.matrix)[[2]]==x[2]))))] <- 1

sample.matrix
  A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T
A 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
D 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
E 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
F 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
G 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
H 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
I 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
J 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
K 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
L 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
M 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
N 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
O 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
P 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
Q 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
R 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
S 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
T 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```